# Linear ODE repeated eigenvalues how to find more than 2 generalized eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

So I've searched around the web for a few hours now, as

(i)
$\mathbf A = \begin{pmatrix}2&1\\0&2\end{pmatrix}$

The characteristic polynomial is $(\lambda-2)^2=0$, so $\lambda=2$, repeated.
A bit of algebra convinces us that $b=(1,0)^t$ is an eigenvector.
Setting $(\mathbf A-\lambda \mathbf I)r=b$, with $r$ and $b$ vectors. Maybe a bit unmotivated but lets proceed. We find that $r=(0,1)^t$ is a solution. Now the solution is

$x(t)= c_1*e^{2t}+c_2(te^{2t}b+e^{2t}r)$

However lets say I have 3 or more repeated eigenvalues, or two eigenvalues that are both eigenvalues what then?

For instance:

$\mathbf A = \begin{pmatrix}1&2&0\\0&1&3/4\\0&0&1\end{pmatrix}$

I find $\lambda=1$ and the vector $b_2=(1,0,0)^t$ is a solution. But I'm not sure how to proceed.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Some things to look for are algebraic and geometric multiplicity, Jordan Normal Form, Generalized eigenvectors and the like and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/178158/linear-algebra-eigenvalues-and-eigenvectors?rq=1, for example

Comment: You Set it up exactly as you did before solve it for 0,0,0 
then find the second solution as you did above now do the exact same thing again but put the second solution on the right hand side instead of the first. you only need to be careful u don't pick the first solution again.

basically $(A-\lambda \mathbf I)c=r$ and make sure you pick c as some linearly Independent vector to the first 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\mathbf A = \begin{pmatrix}1&2&0\\0&1&3/4\\0&0&1\end{pmatrix}$

You should get an Eigensystem as follows:

$$\lambda_1 = 1, v_1 = (1,0,0)$$

$$\lambda_2 = 1, v_2 = (0, 1/2, 0)$$

$$\lambda_3 = 1, v_3 = (0, 0, 2/3)$$

Next, we can write the [*Jordan Normal Form*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form) as:

$$A = \begin{pmatrix}1&2&0\\0&1&3/4\\0&0&1\end{pmatrix} = P J P^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 1/2 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 2/3\end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 & 0\\ 0 & 1 & 1\\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 3/2\end{bmatrix}$$

What do you notice about $J$? What is it made from?

What do you notice about the columns of $P$? What is it made from?

If you would like to step through the manual process, just give a yell.

Here is a very nice example and procedure [need help Jordan base](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/326546/need-help-jordan-base/326575#326575) (most time is overkill, but is also a general procedure).

Comment: Thanks a lot! As I understand from Faust and from the sources you linked. I set $(A-\lambda I)E2=E1$ with Ei eigenvectors. So that gives $(0,1/2,0)$. However for $E3$ I find $2/3x3=1/2$ so the last generalized eigenvector would be   $(0,0,3/4)$. Now the next step. Is the solution$x(t)=c1e^t*E1+c2(te^t*E1+E2e^t)+c3(te^tE1+E2e^t+t^2e^tE3)$ or am I gravely mistaken? Just wanted to say my Linear Algebra didn't include Jordan Normal Forms; I gather it is a kind of "almost-diagonalisation"?

Comment: @LeeWang: Does the excellent response from  Robert Israel make make sense? Yes, you got it! Now, please take the solution I provided above and verify that it indeed solves the original problem by writing the solution. Regards

Comment: To be honest... not at all, I've seen the method with a nilpotent matrix done before, but I haven't got a clue how it works. Regardless I tried verifying that it solves the ODE, but I don't think it works. I think I wrote the answer slightly wrong aswell; shouldn't it be $c_3(t^2e^tE1+te^tE2+E^tE3)$? Maybe I'm making a very elementary mistake but when I fill it in I get that the left hand side (for instance $x_1'$ is a polynomial involving $t^3$ while the righthandside does not and never will. Thanks for all the help.

Comment: I added a link to the trickiest examples. But you are doing great! Keep up the good work! Regards

Comment: I don't think I was very clear in that comment. I meant to say that when you plug in the $x(t)$ given above we get $x'(t)=Ax(t)$. Then the lefthandside will involve terms like $c_3t^3e^t$ while the righthandside is only a linear combination of term all lower degree than $t^3$ so I can't see them becoming equal.

Comment: Review this answer and it will make it clearer http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/289353/system-of-differential-equations-with-triple-eigenvalue

Comment: Very clear thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Write $A = \lambda I + N$ where $N$ is nilpotent (in your example, $N = \pmatrix{0 & 2 & 0\cr 0 & 0 & 3/4\cr 0 & 0 & 0\cr}$ with $N^3 = 0$).  Suppose $N^k = 0$ but $N^{k-1} \ne 0$.  Then your ODE $y' = A y$ has solutions of the form $y(t) = \sum_{j=0}^{k-1} \frac{t^j}{j!} e^{\lambda t} N^j u$ for any vector $u$.  Take a suitable basis...

Comment: How does this work in the general case? How can I be sure that the matrix can always be decomposed into a multiple of the identity matrix and a nilpotent matrix?

Comment: If $\lambda$ is the only eigenvalue of $A$, the characteristic polynomial of $A$ must be $p(z) = (z-\lambda)^n$, and $p(A) = 0$ by the Cayley-Hamilton theorem.  That says that $A - \lambda I$ is nilpotent.